# How to tell if (X,Y) coordinate is within a Circle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

Lets say we have a circle on a MxN grid as shown below.

How can we determine whether the coordinate X,Y falls within the circles coordinates under the assumptions?

- We know the diameter of the circle
- We know that the circle will be always centered!

[image: Example of Circle and Grid]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what does it mean to say that the circle will always be centered?

Comment: You just know the diameter and that the circle *has* a center?

Comment: measure the distance between the center of the circle and the point.  If the distance is smaller than the radius.. then the point must lie within the circle!

Comment: I guess he means it will be centered at the origin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general equation of a circle with radius $R$ and origin $(x_0, y_0)$ is
$$
(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=R^2 \quad (*)
$$
You can derive it from Pythagoras theorem on the sides of a triangle with one rectangular angle $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Example for a circle with origin $(0,0)$:

[image: example]

If a point $(x,y)$ is within the circle, you can interpret it as lying on a circle with smaller radius $r$ and the same origin. As $r<R$ this implies $r^2<R^2$. It fulfills
$$
(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2 < R^2 = (d/2)^2 = d^2/4
$$
where $d = 2R$ is the diameter of the circle. So for interior points equation $(*)$ turns into an inequality with $<$ relation.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how do I get the smaller and larger radius based on my coordinates?

Comment: The smaller radius only played a role for explanation. You got the diameter $d  = 2R$ and probably origin $(0,0)$ so you have everything to plug into both sides. E.g, check if $x^2 +y^2 < (d^2/4)$ or not.

Comment: That worked! And now I get it also more clear, thanks for the Drawing!

Comment: How can i convert R to miles or kilometers (or vice-versa) if coordinates is geographical coords (lat, lon)?

Comment: $R$, the radius is a length. You should keep it the same unit as your Cartesian coordinates $(x, y)$. $(\text{lat}, \text{lon})$ is more complicated, it describes a point on a sphere and depending on your application you might to get into spherical geometry.